# Tensorflow nmt training model with bleu 0.0

Tags: tensorflow, machine-translation

There is my first time to study NMT. I use Tensorflow nmt for my study.

I had followed the example on the Tensorflow nmt(https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt#wmt-german-english).

I have prepared some data (en-zh) and follow the example to tokenize, clean, learn shared BPE and create vocabulary.

After the training, output_dev and output_test show bleu 0.0.

Have I make any mistake on the pre-process data or I make a mistake on the option for training model?

Here is my options to run the nmt.

```
python3 -m nmt.nmt
--src=en --tgt=zh
--vocab_prefix=/home/usr/data/vocab.bpe.32000
--train_prefix=/home/usr/data/train.tok.clean.bpe.32000
--dev_prefix=/home/usr/data/dev2010.tok.bpe.32000
--test_prefix=/home/usr/data/test2014.tok.bpe.32000
--out_dir=/home/usr/model
--num_train_steps=12000
--steps_per_stats=100
--num_layers=2
--num_units=128
--dropout=0.2
--metrics=bleu
```

Any comment and idea will be very welcome. Thanks all.

Comment: It is hard to say, you did not say much. Does the training loss decrease? Does the validation loss decrease? You might be overfitting. How big are your data? It also can be an issue with preprocessing Chinese. Have you looked at the preprocessed data? Do they look OK?

Comment: Hi Jindřich, thanks for your comment. I think i make some mistake on the process data. Now, I re-process on the zh data. And the bleu can be increased. But I think my data is not larger enough. The score is below 10.0